# how to identify index of particular object in qtp

Tags: qtp

I have form, the form contains JavaStaticText fields, and Combo box, and Text fields. I want index of all the items in that form. I tried to get checkpoints, and GET properties but I didn't get the index. How to get particular index,

For example:

```
Name XXXX
Job  XXXX
Country XXXX
```

I want index of Name,Job,Country, XXX individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, here's some code that gets the index of the `9` button on **calc.exe**, you can either base your solution on this or explain how it differs from what you're trying to do.

```
Set Children = Window("Calculator").ChildObjects()
For i = 0 to Children.Count -1
     If Children(i).GetROProperty("text") = "9" Then
        MsgBox "The index of 9 is " & i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

---

**Edit:** From [another question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610692/what-is-the-use-of-objectporoperty-in-qtp/3611968#3611968) I see you're using the property `class_index`, if this is what you want just do:

```
JavaWindow("abc").JavaObject("xyz").GetROProperty("class_index")
```